# Matrix usage in CS

Tags: matrices, mathematical-foundations

I'm studying a major in CS. I'm interested in taking a few extra courses, specifically math to improve my knowledge as future computer scientist.

Right now I'm thinking to take Matrix Fundamentals but I'm not sure if it is going to help me in my CS career. What are its uses apart from arrays in programming?

Comment: matrix definitely helps in a lot of CS area. But since this is about you, can you tell which topic in CS you're particularly interested in? I don't think there is an area in CS where matrix can not help, but perhaps there are areas where matrix are more commonly used than others. Machine learning, for example, really uses matrix a lot relatively.

Comment: really i'm not sure yet, but i do know the difference between CS abd programming, although they overlap are not necessarily the same. i really like math, that's the point. the word matrix has a direct impact in CS of course, but i wonder if it is not only the word itself but the real application

Comment: btw, your question might be considered too broad to ask on this site. but I just answer that anyway.

Comment: It'll definitely help. Moreover, if it's any math course, it'll help with developing the right kind of thinking; taking it won't hurt.

Comment: "Matrix fundamentals" and "Math-127" mean nothing to me or, I suspect, to anyone outside your own university. I've a feeling that the answer to this question is useful only to the asker, which makes it a very bad fit for Stack Exchange, where the goal is to build up a collection of generally useful questions and answers.

Comment: well if this is not the place for asking a question, where is that place? matrix fundamentals is not only given in my college. these kind of destructive comments are completely out of place. if you don't want to answer the question don't do it. moreover if you don't see it as part of your interest that doesn't mean that can't be of interest for someone else

Comment: @blade The correct place (or person) to ask is your advisor and/or the person in charge of the course. They should have a better understanding of what is in the course rather than strangers on the internet.

Comment: I understand the point David made. But even if we rewrite the question so it benefits larger group of people, the question might still be too broad. If the asker had done some more research on his own, he might be able to ask more specificly, like, "Is matrix useful in dealing with database?". The later question might be more appropriate for the site.

Comment: I asked the question here after searching a lot, when you combine matrix and CS on google, what show up are arrays and I looking for matrices from a mathematical point of view, applied to computer science

Comment: What exactly are the contents of these courses? If you add that to the question, I think we have a reasonable question. That said, note that the answer may just be "take more mathematics and TCS, then you will see". To be honest, asking "of what use are matrices?" sounds much like an elementary schooler asking "of what use are these letters?".

Comment: I rolled back to what I consider a reasonable, ontopic question. The later version, "Which of these courses should I take?" are impossible to answer objectively and would thus have to be closed.

Comment: this place has become so negative! When are you guys going to understand that as a students, we are full of doubts, wrong concepts that need answers. I apologize for stupid questions. This web site really needs to divide people in categories. This kind of silly questions are completely normal among newbies and students, and it's not gonna change, because is part of every learning process.

Comment: It depends what is covered in that course. Knowing the title isn't enough. It also depends what you'd do instead of taking that course — “matrix fundamentals” may end up being more useful than X but less useful than Y.

Comment: As a general note, unless you already have a specific industry in mind, it doesn't matter what math courses you take, the important thing is that you do enough math that you're used to mathematical reasoning so that following and writing rigorous proofs is easy for you and that you can pick up whatever you need for a specific job reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you might model real-world things with a set, you model some other real-world things with a matrix. Things that you might model as a matrix ranges includes:

- product-user rating table
- between places distance table
- bitmap images

Modelling things with matrix allow you to see the problem in different perspective. And allow you to see what it might actually mean to apply some matrix operations to it.

For example, you might notice that matrix multiplication on 'distance table' actually gives you a [transitive distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

Or that rank-factorization of product-user rating table actually provides [a mean to categorize users into groups that have the same taste](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_rank_approximation).

Or that know [eigen vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) helps in understanding the [eigen faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) that one corner stone in face recognition.